# PHP - Sort show opening times?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort shop opening times and I've nearly got it..  but not quite.

My array of days / times is:

```
$arr = [[1,3,3,6,0],[5,3,3,6,0],["0900","1300","0900","0200","0900"],["1700","1700","1200","2100","1300"]];
```

I'm building this into an array using:

```
$days = [ 1 => 'Mon', 2 => 'Tue', 3 => 'Wed', 4 => 'Tur', 5 => 'Fri', 6 => 'Sat', 0 => 'Sun' ];
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($arr[0]) ; $i++){
     $array[$i] = array('start' => $days[$arr[0][$i]], 'end' => $days[$arr[1][$i]], 'stime' => $arr[2][$i], 'etime' => $arr[3][$i]);
}
```

When I var_dump the results I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => Mon
            [end] => Fri
            [stime] => 0900
            [etime] => 1700
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => Wed
            [end] => Wed
            [stime] => 1300
            [etime] => 1700
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => Wed
            [end] => Wed
            [stime] => 0900
            [etime] => 1200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => Sat
            [end] => Sat
            [stime] => 0200
            [etime] => 2100
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => Sun
            [end] => Sun
            [stime] => 0900
            [etime] => 1300
        )

)
```

When I loop the results using this :

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    echo "{$v['start']} - {$v['end']} {$v['stime']} : {$v['etime']}<br>";
    
}
```

I get:

```
Mon - Fri 0900 : 1700
Wed - Wed 1300 : 1700
Wed - Wed 0900 : 1200
Sat - Sat 0200 : 2100
Sun - Sun 0900 : 1300
```

What I'm trying to get is:
Note The position of the two Wed entries.

```
Mon - Fri 0900 : 1700
Wed - Wed 0900 : 1200
Wed - Wed 1300 : 1700
Sat - Sat 0200 : 2100
Sun - Sun 0900 : 1300
```

I've tried:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'stime'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC,
                array_column($array, 'start'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
            $array);
```

Which results in:

```
Sat - Sat 0200 : 2100
Mon - Fri 0900 : 1700
Sun - Sun 0900 : 1300
Wed - Wed 0900 : 1200
Wed - Wed 1300 : 1700
```

Which orders the Wed entries correctly but messes the other entries.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by making a couple of changes. Firstly, add a

```
7 => 'Sun'
```

entry to your `$days` array, and convert `0` values in `$arr` to `7` to allow `Sun` to sort at the end of the days. Secondly, store the numeric day values from `$arr` in `$array` as this makes them easier to sort; convert them to the day names on output. Then you can use `array_multisort` to sort the data as you desire, although note that you need to sort by `start` and then `stime`, not the other way around as you are doing. In total:

```
$arr = [[1,3,3,6,0],[5,3,3,6,0],["0900","1300","0900","0200","0900"],["1700","1700","1200","2100","1300"]];
$days = [ 1 => 'Mon', 2 => 'Tue', 3 => 'Wed', 4 => 'Tur', 5 => 'Fri', 6 => 'Sat', 0 => 'Sun', 7 => 'Sun' ];
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($arr[0]) ; $i++){
     $array[$i] = array('start' => $arr[0][$i] == 0 ? 7 : $arr[0][$i], 
                        'end' => $arr[1][$i], 
                        'stime' => $arr[2][$i],
                        'etime' => $arr[3][$i]
                        );
}
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'start'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC,
                array_column($array, 'stime'), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
                $array);
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    echo "{$days[$v['start']]} - {$days[$v['end']]} {$v['stime']} : {$v['etime']}<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Mon - Fri 0900 : 1700<br>
Wed - Wed 0900 : 1200<br>
Wed - Wed 1300 : 1700<br>
Sat - Sat 0200 : 2100<br>
Sun - Sun 0900 : 1300<br>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8OBNh)

Comment: Thanks this has really helped :)